# How do I capture the properties I want from a string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope you are well I have the following string:

```
"{\"code\":0,\"description\":\"Done\",\"response\":{\"id\":\"8-717-2346\",\"idType\":\"CIP\",\"suscriptionId\":\"92118213\"},....\"childProducts\":[]}}"...
```

To which I'm trying to capture the attributes: id, idType and subscriptionId and map them as a dataframe, but the entire body of the .cvs puts it in a single row so it is almost impossible for me to work without index

desired output:

```py
id,  idType, suscriptionID
0.   '7-84-1811', 'CIP', 21312421412
1.   '1-232-42',  'IO' , 21421e324
```

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

path = '/example.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
normalize_df = json.load(df)
print(df)
```

Comment: That string is JSON, so just use `json.loads()` to parse it into a dictionary. Or use `pd.read_json()` to read it directly into a dataframe.

Comment: hi @Barmar try that, but it returns this: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not DataFrame

Comment: `df` is already a dataframe, not the string you showed at the top of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your string is in JSON format, you can do this.
drop columns, transpose, and get headers right.

```
toEscape = "{\"code\":0,\"description\":\"Done\",\"response\":{\"id\":\"8-717-2346\",\"idType\":\"CIP\",\"suscriptionId\":\"92118213\"}}"

json_string = toEscape.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')

df = pd.read_json(json_string)

df = df.drop(["code","description"], axis=1)

df  = df.transpose().reset_index().drop("index", axis=1)

df.to_csv("user_details.csv")
```

the output looks like this:

```
id  idType  suscriptionId
0   8-717-2346  CIP 92118213
```

Thank you for the question.